# How can I increase max-http-header-size for Vue app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I get information in headers after redirect from other app and page does not open. I get next error in console of page: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)**
I read about **max-http-header-size**. How can I use it in Vue app for increasing header size?

Comment: Are you talking about the dev server? Was your project created using Vue CLI and, if so, which version?

Comment: It seems some extension or the current state of my browser is sending too large of headers to the server instance. I tried in incognito and it worked fine. Now to track down what's being sent over  I had too many session cookies built up on `localhost` from multiple apps. Hope this can help someone that runs across this like I did.

Comment: I cleared cookies for localhost and it fixed my issue, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem.
I installed [node.js](http://%20https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.12.0/) that has http headers sizes more than 8kb.

Answer (score 0):

By default the **max-http-header-size is 8KB** for node, Either you can upgrade the node version or you can just can header setting which are mentioned below.
First set up the proxy. Then open the vue-cli-service.cmd file which can be found in **node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service.cmd** and modify it with the changes mentioned.

- "%_prog%" **"--max-http-header-size=9999999"** "%dp0%..@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js" %*